# number that is divisible by its containing digits

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, math

[image]I'm making a program to receive an input and determine if it is a self dividing number.

> A self-dividing number is a number that is divisible by every digit it contains.
>
> It should output “This number is self-dividing” if it is otherwise, it should output “This number is NOT self-dividing”.

For example, 128 is a self-dividing number because 1, 2, and 8 are all divisors of 128. As another example, 102 is not a self-diving number because it contains a digit 0. As a 3rd example, 26 is not a self-dividing number, because it’s not divisible by 6.

```js
function run() {

  var output = document.getElementById("output");

  var a = parseInt(prompt("Submit number: ", ""));

  var num = 0;

  while (a > 0) {
    var num = a % 10

    if (a % num == 0) {
      a = Math.floor(a / 10);
    } else {
      output.innerHTML = "This number is not self dividing."
      break;
    }
  }

  output.innerHTML = "This number is a self dividing number."
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <button onclick="run()">Submit Number</button>
</div>
<p id="output"></p>
```

The code does not run as expected and only outputs "This number is a self dividing number."

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Im receiving a number and based on the number, output if it is divisible by the digits it contains or not. I have provided an example in the question.

Comment: A few tips: do not reassign `a`, after all, you want to check if it is divisible by various other numbers (its digits). First, try to write a loop that produces all digits of `a` without modifying `a`. You can create a copy of `a` which you can modify.

Comment: A general tip: please state what your problem is and ask a specific question. Your "question" doesn't contain any question.

Comment: The code does not run as expected and only outputs "This number is a self dividing number." Should I include a break in the else statement?

Comment: Also add a `break` in else condition and manipulate output in the end only if `a == 0`.

Comment: Ok, looked closely and you are manipulating the same `a` which is not correct.

Comment: @nice_dev how do I not manipulate?

Comment: @nice_dev What do I have to do so it is not manipulated?

Comment: store it in a separate variable. Say `var temp = a`. Now, do all checks with `temp % num == 0`.

Comment: @nice_dev can you edit the code for me please

Comment: @SinaHeidari See this https://pastebin.com/LyiLqDrH It also handles divide by zero.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A034838

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following successively finds the least significant digit `lsd`, and tests it (can't be zero, `n/lsd` can't have a remainder).

If `lsd` fails the test, we return `false`.

If it passes the test, then we divide by ten and floor the result to "chop off" the current least significant digit. We store the result in `prefix`.

If `prefix` is zero, then we have no more digits to test, no digits have failed the test and we return `true`.

Otherwise we have more digits to test and pass `prefix` (along with `n`) to `isSelfDividing` recursively to continue checking.

```js
function isSelfDividing(n, prefix=n) {      
  const lsd = prefix%10

  if(lsd === 0 || n%lsd) return false

  prefix = Math.floor(prefix/10)
  return prefix === 0 || isSelfDividing(n, prefix)
}

console.log(isSelfDividing(138)) // false
console.log(isSelfDividing(128)) // true
console.log(isSelfDividing(102)) // false
console.log(isSelfDividing(0))   // false
console.log(isSelfDividing(1))   // true
```

This updates an earlier answer that handled zero differently.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can implement this logic:

```
function run() {

  var output = document.getElementById("output");

  var num = parseInt(prompt("Submit number: ", ""));

  let n = num;

  while(num){
    let temp = num %10;
    if(n % temp !== 0){
      output.innerHTML = "This number is a not self dividing number."
      return;
    }
    num = Math.floor(num/10);
  }

  output.innerHTML = "This number is a self dividing number."
}
```

Working Demo: https://codepen.io/TheKetan2/pen/rNLOrGR?editors=1010

[image]

Vanila JS solution:

```
// using string to array conversion :

function selfDivisible(num){
  for(let n of [...num.toString()]){
      if(num % parseInt(n) !== 0){
      return "not divisible"
    }
  }
  return "divisible"
}
selfDivisible(128)

//----------------------------------------------------------------//

//plain mathematical implementation:

function selfDivisible(num){
  let n = num;

  while(num){
    let temp = num %10;
    if(n % temp !== 0){
      return "not divisible";
    }
    num = Math.floor(num/10);
  }
  return "divisible"
}
selfDivisible(221)
```

Comment: Can I do it without converting it to a string??

Comment: sure you can. but string to array approach is very clean that's why I implemented using it.

Comment: I cant use arrays or strings. Could you give me suggestion based on my code

Comment: https://codepen.io/TheKetan2/pen/rNLOrGR?editors=1010

here is full code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223313/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-sina-heidari).

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
p {
  background-color: aqua;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Output is: <span id="output"></span></p>

<script>
let output = document.querySelector('#output');
function run() {
  let num = prompt("Submit a number: ","").toString();
  
  let digits = num.split('');
  
  let isSelfDividing = true;
  
  digits.forEach(digit=>{
    if(Number(num)%Number(digit)!==0){
      isSelfDividing = false;
    }
  })
  
  if(isSelfDividing) {
    output.innerHTML = 'This number IS self-dividing';
  }
  else {
    output.innerHTML = 'This number IS NOT self-dividing';
  }
  }

run();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```